# How to get received messages from twitter api via php

Tags: php, api, twitter

I want to get all my received messages from twitter api but I get empty object on response. i use [Twitter for PHP](https://github.com/dg/twitter-php) library and that is my code

```
$twitter = new Twitter($CONSUMER_KEY, $CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$statuses = $twitter->request("direct_messages/events/list", "GET");
print_r($statuses);
```

the response is empty object

```
stdClass Object([events] => Array())
```

Comment: From the [docu](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/overview): "_You can retrieve Direct Messages from up to the past 30 days with GET direct_messages/events/list._" Have you made sure you received direct messages within the last 30 days?

Comment: it works.
Thanks bro, I noticed that i already not received any messages at last month